# Name of a graph that shows various strengths

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for the name of a graph used to show various strengths. It is a polygon and may look like this:

```
    _
|       |
|       |
|     * |
    _
```

Where the star is the value relative to 8 characteristics. It is most "like" the bottom right two characteristics and least "like" the characteristics on the top left.

Also, this graph is used in, for example, Pokemon to show various strengths and weaknesses of a particular Pokemon.

What is this graph called?

Answer (score 1):

[Polar Chart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=polar+chart&biw=1366&bih=633&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=RGKNVcanMseU7QbWu7zYBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAA&dpr=1) seems to give a good resemblance.